# Hide all next tr td until next tr th

Tags: jquery, toggle, show-hide

it should be simple but this jQuery function are taking a element to much, it even hide the jQuery I think.

What I will like to do, is when a person click a **tr th**, all next **tr td** should be hide until next **tr th**.

How can I get this code to work??

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <style>
th {  background:#dad;
      font-weight:bold;
      font-size:16px; 
      width: 50%;
}
td {  background:red;
      font-weight:bold;
      font-size:16px; 
      width: 50%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <table id="example">
    <tr>
      <th>
        <button>Show it 3</button>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <button>Show it 2</button>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test 4</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

    <script>
      $('#example tr th').click( function() {
        //alert($(this).parent().html())
        $(this).parent().nextUntil('tr th').toggle();
      })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a class to he `tr` elements that has `th` element:

```
<table id="example">
    <tr>
      <th class='toggle'>
        <button>Show it 3</button>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='toggle'>
      <th>
        <button>Show it 2</button>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test 4</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

```
$('#example tr th').click( function() {
   $(this).parent().nextUntil('.toggle').toggle();
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kgBv/3/)

Comment: Thanks. I used you solution because it is so easy.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it using mostly the dom

```
  $('#example tr td button').on('click',function(e){
       var curr = this;
       // get the tr where the button was clicked
       while(curr.nodeType!=='tr') curr = curr.parentNode;
       // now get sibling nodes
       while((curr=curr.nextSibling)){
           if(curr.firstChild.nodeType==='td') $(curr).hide();
           else if(curr.firstChild.nodeType==='tr') return;
       }
    }
```

Or, with more jQuery:

```
$('#example tr td button').on('click',function(e){
    var siblings = $(this).siblings();
    for(var i=0; i < siblings.length; i++){
        if(siblings[i].find('td').length) $(siblings[i]).hide();
        else if(siblings[i].find('tr').length) return;
    }
 });
```