# Comparing "this" object with Object in DOM Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

This question is the root cause for my question.

[Hide all next tr td until next tr th](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11414965/hide-all-next-tr-td-until-next-tr-th)

As already two answers being posted , I thought of trying something different

Javascript:

```
$(function(){ 
    var thList = $('td');
    $('td').click(function(){
        for( i =0; i < thList.length;i++){
            // What to do here
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
    <table border="2">
        <tr>
            <td> 1 </td>
            <td> 2 </td>
            <td> 3 </td>
        </tr>
    <table>
```

What am doing here is 
Assigning click event to `<TH>` element. And on load , am getting all the `<TH>` in the DOM in an Array.

Now, my logic is. Iterate the for loop and if the clicked `TH` is not the one in the `for loop`, then hide it.

What i tried is

```
if ( thList[i] != $(this)) { thList[i].style.display = 'none' }
```

But this does not seem to be working. what code I need to put there to compare the object

Comment: Are the `th` elements being added **after** page load?

Comment: From the code you've posted it seems that the clicked `TH` will *always* be in the `thList` array.

Comment: Unless i'm misunderstanding the question, you don't need to jump through the loops to achieve what you want. in the click handler $(this) already refers to the element that was clicked.

Comment: @999 Yeh .it will be in the list. Am excluding the one which is clicked

Comment: Dimitri Yes. you are correct. $(this) always represents the one that is clicked. So, i excluding the one that is clicked , and hiding the remaining from the array

Comment: Have you tried with any actual `th` elements?

Comment: sidenote: next time only try to post the relevant code instead of the whole document - this shortens the question and more people will actually read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the fact, that you example markup does not contain any `th`-elements, you could try the following:

```
$('td').click(function(){

    var $tdList = $('td').not(this); // <- get all th's and exlude the clicked element

    $tdList.each(function(){this.style.display = 'none'; });
});
```

or even better, use jQuery, you don't need a each wrapper then:

```
$tdList.hide();
```

Since jQuery saves you a lot of work, try to use it whenever you can - use the `each()` instead of for-loops and use `.css()` (or even more dedicated methods like `.hide()`) instead of the native `.style` - this should shorten your code significantly.

Answer (score 2):

When you are accessing the items in a jQuery object, you get them as DOM elements, not as new jQuery objects. So, you should compare it to the element reference directly, not wrap the element reference in a jQuery object:

```
for (i = 0; i < thList.length; i++) {
  if ( thList[i] != this) { thList[i].style.display = 'none' }
}
```

You can also use the [`not` method](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to get a collection without the current element:

```
thList.not(this).each(function(){ this.style.display = 'none'; });
```

Of course, using the [`css` method](http://api.jquery.com/css/) it becomes even simpler:

```
thList.not(this).css('display', 'none');
```

---

Word of caution: The cells in tables are not really separate elements that you can just hide without affecting the other cells in the table. The table can show unexpected behaviour when you hide cells in it.

Comment: Yeh. tried it but not working. But if am not wrong. When i bind a jQuery event, i will be getting the jQuery wrapper instead of normal DOM object

Comment: $('th').click(function(){
     thList.not(this).each(function(){ alert('');this.style.display = 'none'; });
    });

Is this wat u mean. Sorry :(. Not working!

Comment: @madhairsilence: In a jQuery event, `this` is a reference to the DOM element, not to a jQuery object containing the element. I tried both versions, and they do work: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/ddMWd/

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
thList.click(function() {
    thList.not(this).css("display", "none");
});
```

For performance reason you could delegate the event instead:

```
$("#yourtable").on("click", "th", function(event) {
    thList.not(event.target).css("display", "none");
});
```

I didn't test it, but should works.

However I'm curious about the UI: if the TH are hidden in this way, they can't be displayed anymore after the first click of any of them.

Answer (score 2):

1-You `$(this)` is diferent of `this` once is a jquery object
2-You dont have a TH element here is the code similar that you want but whit td's

```
$(function(){
var tdList = $('td');
$('td').click(function(){
    tdList.hide();
    $(this).show();
    //OR  tdList.not(this).hide();

  });
});
```

Comment: looks nice, I'd prefer `tdList.not(this).hide();` though.